# Google Maps API v2 api key

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android app that uses the Google Maps API v2.  I generated an API key at the google site, but it always becomes inactive after a day or so.

How do I get a more permanent API Key so I can have user test my app without it going inactive every day?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "inactive"?

Comment: Well, after a day or so the map just comes up blank.  When I log in to the Google API Access site and go to API Access, it show Inactive in the status line.  So, I need to generate a new key and r-build my app.  Maybe I am doing something wrong, but the app does work right when to key is ok.

Comment: "it show Inactive in the status line" -- that's bizarre. I have never seen that. The keys I set up weeks ago are all working just fine.

Comment: LOL, that is what everyone tells me, but it really does happen. In fact if I go to the google site and generate a new one it tell me how long it is good for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are clicking the "Generate new key" link to the right of your existing key. That is for replacing an existing key, and the original key will be removed after 24 hours.

Instead, click "Create new Android key..." at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yes, that is what i am doing, I will try what you say.

Comment: Ok, I generated a new key that way so I will give it a try.  I did not do that because when I use that method of generating a key I need to put in the SHA1 fingerprint and such.

Comment: You will be needing SHA1 fingerprint.